# How do I customize the ASP.Net Bubble Event to pass an additional variable?

Tags: asp.net, web-user-controls

I am using BubbleEvent to give events from a web user control to its parent (which is a Default.aspx with code behind page).

I would like to use BubbleEvent to not only pass the sender and event, but also an integer or another variable.

Is there a way to add a parameter to the BubbleEvent, or is there a different way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here are the steps you need to follow**

1. Create a class that inherits EventArgs
2. Create a property in this class for the additional data that you need to pass
3. When calling back the BubbleEvent, pass the sender and the new inherited class instead of the regular EventArgs class. Let me know if you need additional details.